# Attach a context menu (context.js) to a node in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, graph, contextmenu, cytoscape.js

Since the nodes in a cytoscape.js graph are on a canvas I'm not sure how to go about marrying the two together.

I guess a generic version of the question is, how can jQuery find a node?

I've tried the `cytoscape.js-cxtmenu` circular context menu. And while it's very cool, we'd like a more traditional popup menu. In another SO question (which is closed) [context.js](http://lab.jakiestfu.com/contextjs/) was recommended.

Reusing the `demo.js` from that page it seems line I need to modify this line

```
context.attach($("#layer2-node").get(0))
```

and replace it with something like

```
context.attach(document.getElementById('cy').elements())
```

however, that doesn't seem to work.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you have to create dummy DOM elements per node as needed to call a DOM library.  This is the approach the qtip extension uses, creating divs on demand.

If you can specify positions/offsets in the lib, then you could alternatively just use your container DOM element.